# How do i call add_to_cart jquery function to php for getting the input quantity value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

So, I am trying to get the quantity of the user input and if it matches the total quantity stock then it will be sold as a wholesale product. But I cannot get the jquery function `add_cart_func('qty')` working. Please help!! Trying for hours. 
Edit- I have added the declaration of `let qty = $("#"+type).val();`. I have used `radio` for users to choose if they want to buy `wholesale` or `retail`.

```
<?php 
    if ($this->session->user=='good') 
    {   
        $price = $single['pro_quantity_stock'] == add_cart_func('qty') ? $single["pro_wholesale"] : $single["pro_retail"];  
?>
        <input type="radio" name="tt" value="Wholesale" onclick="doDisplay(this);"/>&nbsp;Buy Wholesale
        <span id="wholesales" style="display:none">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <?php 
                if ($single['pro_wholesale'] != NULL) 
                { 
            ?>
                    <input name="qty" class ='txtbx' size="10" type="number" id="txtNumber" value="<?php echo $single['pro_quantity_stock'] ?>"  disabled />

            <?php
                }
                else
                {
            ?>
                    <input name="qty" class ='txtbx' size="10" type="number" id="txtNumber" value="0"  disabled />
            <?php
                }
            ?>
        </span>
        <br />

        <input type="radio" name="tt" value="Retail" onclick="doDisplay(this);"/> Buy Retail
        <span id="retails" style="display:none">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <input name="qty" class ='txtbx1' size="10" type="number" id="txtNumber1" />
        </span>
        <br />

        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-normal" onclick="add_cart_func(<?= $single['id'] ?>, '<?= $single["pro_title"] ?>', '<?= $price ?>')">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> ADD TO CART
        </a>
```

Comment: Where did you declare and define "type"-> $("#"+type).val();

Comment: I have added the declaration to the question.

Comment: you have the function defined `add_cart_func(id, name, price){}` yet you call it like this: `add_cart_func('qty')`

Comment: I am getting this error-  Call to undefined function add_cart_func()

Comment: because you have a javascript function `add_cart_func(id, name, price){}` and you also try to call a php function add_cart_func('qty'). That doesn't work. Php is server side and executed first, then comes javascript/jquery clientside. Read about Codeigniter framework [MVC approach](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/overview/mvc.html) and [jQuery Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Can you please tell how do I get the quantity of user input to check if it matches with products quantities

Comment: please show your php function `add_cart_func('qty')` first

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: I still do not see your function declarations... You only added the function call. and it's also confusing that you're trying to use `add_cart_func()` as both a php and a javascript function which is really confusing

Answer (score 0):

There's a serious misunderstanding on your question. The one being that you're trying to use PHP in a real-time client logic. Here're some important things to note:

1. PHP is server side and Javascript/Jquery are client side. So the php on your pages is executed before the pages are returned to the browser. AS soon as the pages reach the browser no php runs at that point, you're only left with client site javascript.
2. There's a function `add_cart_func()` which is not clear if it's declared both as a php function and javascript function before you did not provide their declarations. So we cannot really assume that is the case but it seems like you're trying to use either a php function as a javascript function like here `onclick="add_cart_func(<?= $single['id'] ?>` or perhaps it's a javascript function and you're trying to use it within your php code.
3. PHP and Javascript are not interchangeable as per bullet 1, so to be assisted you will need to provide  the declarations of